# Command runs in command line but not in Perl script

Tags: perl, unix

I have a Unix command that takes a input.dump file and has it analyzed by tshark. That analysis is then filtered through grep for source and destination information and then filtered through grep again for Vmware. The final output is placed in a file called input.useful for later processing.

Here's the problem. When I run it through the command line, it runs perfectly. For my assignment, I have to write a Perl script that runs that command. I have tried playing around with spacing in my script, with using single or double quotes, adding and removing filepaths, etc. The current code just receives the error :

```
grep: Vmware: no such file or directory.
```

Help me understand why this might work in command line, but not in Perl. I am running Ubuntu 13.04 through VMWare.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

#execute tshark command to extract data from dump file

system("tshark –r input.dump -V|egrep \"Source:|Destination:|Time since reference or first frame:|Source port:|Destination port:\"|grep –v \"Vmware\">input.useful");
```

Comment: If this is what you are doing, why do you need Perl in the equation at all?

Comment: Because that's the assignment. The Perl script runs this part and then takes the output and runs it through a C program that does further work on the data.

Comment: But then you can just `open(handle, "tshark|")` and do all the complex grepping in Perl, and not writing to a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By inference, the command you run at the shell command line is:

```
tshark –r input.dump -V |
egrep "Source:|Destination:|Time since reference or first frame:|Source port:|Destination port:" |
grep –v "Vmware" >input.useful
```

The simplest way to run the 'same' command in Perl is to wrap that up verbatim, using the extraordinarily useful `qq{}` notation to choose your double quotes as something other than `"`.  Or, indeed, to include it in single quotes, possibly even `q{}`.

```
my $cmd = q{
tshark –r input.dump -V |
egrep "Source:|Destination:|Time since reference or first frame:|Source port:|Destination port:" |
grep –v "Vmware" >input.useful
};
```

And now you can run that with `system`:

```
system $cmd;
```

---

> I tried your suggestion and I get the exact same error as before.

Very odd.  I tried this, which is close to isomorphic with your example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $cmd = q{
ls -l |
egrep "merge|sort" |
grep -v 'cpp$' > list.out
};

system $cmd;
```

And it ran without errors, producing the `list.out` file:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   2064 Sep 21 13:54 keysort1.c
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   2602 Sep 21 13:54 keysort2.c
-rwxr-xr-x   1 jleffler  staff  14488 Sep 21 18:28 merge
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   6274 Sep 21 13:54 merge.c
drwxr-xr-x   3 jleffler  staff    102 Sep 21 18:28 merge.dSYM
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   8633 Sep 21 06:49 mergesort.c
-rwxr-xr-x   1 jleffler  staff  26232 Sep 21 18:01 mergesort2
drwxr-xr-x   3 jleffler  staff    102 Sep 21 18:01 mergesort2.dSYM
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff   3335 Sep 21 17:25 msort.c
-rw-r--r--   1 jleffler  staff  16134 Sep 21 06:49 sorttest.c
```

which is the currently the correct output for my SO questions directory on the 'sort-merge' branch.

Can you try a similar test?  What is your shell (`$SHELL`) set to?

Can you build your command up in stages?

1. Run '`tshark -r input.dump -V > input.raw`' via `system` and see what you get.
2. Run '`tshark -r input.dump -V | egrep "Source:|Destination:" > input.parboiled` and see what you get.
3. Run '`cat input.parboiled | grep -v "Vmware" > input.semiuseful`' and see what you get.

Etc.  Something should give the game away.  In case of extremis, try adding `set -x;` before the command so you see what the shell thinks it is running.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I get the exact same error as before. I would really like to understand why this isn't working when everything I've seen says it should?

Comment: I tried your suggestions and everything worked perfectly. In the course of that, my original script started working. I wish I knew what I did to fix it. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

You would only get that error if there was an non-option argument between `-v` and `Vmware` such as the `XXX` in the following:

```
$ grep -v XXX Vmware
grep: Vmware: No such file or directory
```

Either you didn't post the code you actually ran, or the `grep` you are executing isn't normal (e.g. a shall alias that wraps the real `grep`).